# mod_rewrite conflict with combining 2 conditions/rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using this mod_rewrite rule to **avoid .php endings** on our website:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Works great, website.com/login.php becomes website.com/login

Now I'd like to introduce an username system using **website.com/username**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Both rules/conditions are working as expected, but using them together at the same time will cause conflicts such as the custom *"No profile found"* message, even on pages like *terms.php*

Any chance to combine these rules/conditions to first check if there is an existing .php file and if not, try the profile username? Or even a hint how to solve this issue the better way?

Example:
*website.com/netsetter*

1. If netsetter.php exists, use netsetter.php
2. If netsetter.php not exists, use profile.php?user=netsetter

Update (full config):

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs">

DirectoryIndex index.php

# Apache configuration file
# httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

# Note .htaccess files are an overhead, this logic should be in your Apache
# config if possible: httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

# Techniques in here adapted from all over, including:
#   Kroc Camen: camendesign.com/.htaccess
#   perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/
#   Sample .htaccess file of CMS MODx: modxcms.com

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Better website experience for IE users
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
#  github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
# Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
    # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|oex|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cross-domain AJAX requests
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve cross-domain Ajax requests, disabled by default.
# enable-cors.org
# code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity

#  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
#  </IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CORS-enabled images (@crossorigin)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
# developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image
# blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html
# hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/
# wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/crossoriginAttribute

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
        <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Webfont access
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proper MIME type for all files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# JavaScript
#   Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways)
#   tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
AddType application/javascript         js jsonp
AddType application/json               json

# Audio
AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg
AddType audio/mp4                      m4a f4a f4b

# Video
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/webm                     webm
AddType video/x-flv                    flv

# SVG
#   Required for svg webfonts on iPad
#   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

# Webfonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff        woff

# Assorted types
AddType image/x-icon                        ico
AddType image/webp                          webp
AddType text/cache-manifest                 appcache manifest
AddType text/x-component                    htc
AddType application/xml                     rss atom xml rdf
AddType application/x-chrome-extension      crx
AddType application/x-opera-extension       oex
AddType application/x-xpinstall             xpi
AddType application/octet-stream            safariextz
AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp
AddType text/x-vcard                        vcf
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash       swf
AddType text/vtt                            vtt

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allow concatenation from within specific js and css files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# e.g. Inside of script.combined.js you could have
#   <!--#include file="libs/jquery-1.5.0.min.js" -->
#   <!--#include file="plugins/jquery.idletimer.js" -->
# and they would be included into this single file.

# This is not in use in the boilerplate as it stands. You may
# choose to use this technique if you do not have a build process.

#<FilesMatch "\.combined\.js$">
#  Options +Includes
#  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES application/javascript application/json
#  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
#</FilesMatch>

#<FilesMatch "\.combined\.css$">
#  Options +Includes
#  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/css
#  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
#</FilesMatch>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
        application/javascript \
        application/json \
        application/rss+xml \
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
        application/x-font-ttf \
        application/xhtml+xml \
        application/xml \
        font/opentype \
        image/svg+xml \
        image/x-icon \
        text/css \
        text/html \
        text/plain \
        text/x-component \
        text/xml
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# These are pretty far-future expires headers.
# They assume you control versioning with filename-based cache busting
# Additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache
#   www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

# If you don't use filenames to version, lower the CSS and JS to something like
# "access plus 1 week".

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    # Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
    ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Your document html
    ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Data
    ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Feed
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"

    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

    # Media: images, video, audio
    ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

    # HTC files  (css3pie)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

    # Webfonts
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

    # CSS and JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent mobile network providers from modifying your site
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The following header prevents modification of your code over 3G on some
# European providers.
# This is the official 'bypass' suggested by O2 in the UK.

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
# </IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# ETag removal
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we're sending far-future expires, we don't need ETags for
# static content.
#   developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The following directives stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers - in
# combination with the "ExpiresByType" rules for images (see above).

# BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
# BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
# BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
# SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set Keep-Alive Header
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Keep-Alive allows the server to send multiple requests through one
# TCP-connection. Be aware of possible disadvantages of this setting. Turn on
# if you serve a lot of static content.

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#   Header set Connection Keep-Alive
# </IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cookie setting from iframes
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow cookies to be set from iframes (for IE only)
# If needed, specify a path or regex in the Location directive.

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#   Header set P3P "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\""
# </IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and
# features. FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.

# Some cloud hosting services require RewriteBase to be set
# If using the h5bp in a subdirectory, use `RewriteBase /foo` instead where
# 'foo' is your directory.

# If your web host doesn't allow the FollowSymlinks option, you may need to
# comment it out and use `Options +SymLinksOfOwnerMatch`, but be aware of the
# performance impact

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The same content should never be available under two different URLs -
# especially not with and without "www." at the beginning, since this can cause
# SEO problems (duplicate content). That's why you should choose one of the
# alternatives and redirect the other one.

# By default option 1 (no "www.") is activated.
# no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

# If you'd prefer to use option 2, just comment out all option 1 lines
# and uncomment option 2.

# IMPORTANT: NEVER USE BOTH RULES AT THE SAME TIME!

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 1:
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com".

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 2:
# Rewrite "example.com -> www.example.com".
# Be aware that the following rule might not be a good idea if you use "real"
# subdomains for certain parts of your website.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Built-in filename-based cache busting
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# If you're not using the build script to manage your filename version revving,
# you might want to consider enabling this, which will route requests for
# /css/style.20110203.css to /css/style.css

# To understand why this is important and a better idea than all.css?v1231,
# read: github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/wiki/cachebusting

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
# </IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent SSL cert warnings
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL cert warnings, e.g. prevent
# https://www.example.com when your cert only allows https://secure.example.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent 404 errors for non-existing redirected folders
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# without -MultiViews, Apache will give a 404 for a rewrite if a folder of the
# same name does not exist.
# webmasterworld.com/apache/3808792.htm

Options -MultiViews

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Custom 404 page
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# You can add custom pages to handle 500 or 403 pretty easily, if you like.
# If you are hosting your site in subdirectory, adjust this accordingly
#    e.g. ErrorDocument 404 /subdir/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# UTF-8 encoding
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# A little more security
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a
# default document Usually you should leave this activated, because you
# shouldn't allow everybody to surf through every folder on your server (which
# includes rather private places like CMS system folders).
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

# Block access to "hidden" directories or files whose names begin with a
# period. This includes directories used by version control systems such as
# Subversion or Git.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

# Block access to backup and source files. These files may be left by some
# text/html editors and pose a great security danger, when anyone can access
# them.
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

# If your server is not already configured as such, the following directive
# should be uncommented in order to set PHP's register_globals option to OFF.
# This closes a major security hole that is abused by most XSS (cross-site
# scripting) attacks. For more information: http://php.net/register_globals
#
# IF REGISTER_GLOBALS DIRECTIVE CAUSES 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERRORS:
#
# Your server does not allow PHP directives to be set via .htaccess. In that
# case you must make this change in your php.ini file instead. If you are
# using a commercial web host, contact the administrators for assistance in
# doing this. Not all servers allow local php.ini files, and they should
# include all PHP configurations (not just this one), or you will effectively
# reset everything to PHP defaults. Consult www.php.net for more detailed
# information about setting PHP directives.

# php_flag register_globals Off

# Rename session cookie to something else, than PHPSESSID
# php_value session.name sid

# Disable magic quotes (This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.)
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# Do not show you are using PHP
# Note: Move this line to php.ini since it won't work in .htaccess
# php_flag expose_php Off

# Level of log detail - log all errors
# php_value error_reporting -1

# Write errors to log file
# php_flag log_errors On

# Do not display errors in browser (production - Off, development - On)
# php_flag display_errors Off

# Do not display startup errors (production - Off, development - On)
# php_flag display_startup_errors Off

# Format errors in plain text
# Note: Leave this setting 'On' for xdebug's var_dump() output
# php_flag html_errors Off

# Show multiple occurrence of error
# php_flag ignore_repeated_errors Off

# Show same errors from different sources
# php_flag ignore_repeated_source Off

# Size limit for error messages
# php_value log_errors_max_len 1024

# Don't precede error with string (doesn't accept empty string, use whitespace if you need)
# php_value error_prepend_string " "

# Don't prepend to error (doesn't accept empty string, use whitespace if you need)
# php_value error_append_string " "

# Increase cookie security
<IfModule php5_module>
    php_value session.cookie_httponly true
</IfModule>

# Avoid directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Protecting *.tpl files
<Files "*.tpl">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/uploads_user/(.*)$ /uploads_user/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?user_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^@([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?user_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?user_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /profile.php?user=$1$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/albums/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /album_file.php?user_id=$1&album_id=$2&media_id=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/albums/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /album_file.php?user=$1&album_id=$2&media_id=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/albums/([0-9]+)/?$ /album.php?user_id=$1&album_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/albums/([0-9]+)/?$ /album.php?user=$1&album_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/albums/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /album.php?user_id=$1&album_id=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/albums/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /album.php?user=$1&album_id=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/albums/?$ /albums.php?user_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/albums/?$ /albums.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/netmails/?$ /netmails.php?user_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/netmails/?$ /netmails.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/netmails/([0-9]+)/?$ /netmails.php?user_id=$1&netmail_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/netmails/([0-9]+)/?$ /netmails.php?user=$1&netmail_id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/blog/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?user_id=$1&blogentry_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/blog/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?user=$1&blogentry_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/blog/([^/]+)?$ /blog.php?user_id=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/blog/([^/]+)?$ /blog.php?user=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/blog/?$ /blog.php?user_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/blog/?$ /blog.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/trackback/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog_ajax.php?task=trackback&user=$1&blogentry_id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group.php?group_id=$1$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/album/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group_album.php?group_id=$2&groupalbum_id=$3$4 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/album/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group_album_file.php?group_id=$2&groupalbum_id=$3&groupmedia_id=$4$5 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/discussion/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group_discussion_view.php?group_id=$2&grouptopic_id=$3$4 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/discussion/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group_discussion_view.php?group_id=$2&grouptopic_id=$3&grouppost_id=$4$5 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/poll/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group_poll.php?group_id=$2&poll_id=$3$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/audio/?$ /audio.php?user_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/audio/?$ /audio.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/videos/?$ /videos.php?user_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/videos/?$ /videos.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/videos/([0-9]+)/?$ /video.php?user_id=$1&video_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/videos/([0-9]+)/?$ /video.php?user=$1&video_id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/polls/([0-9]+)/?$ /poll.php?user_id=$1&poll_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/polls/([0-9]+)/?$ /poll.php?user=$1&poll_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/polls/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /poll.php?user_id=$1&poll_id=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/polls/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /poll.php?user=$1&poll_id=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/polls/?$ /polls.php?user_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/polls/?$ /polls.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^de https\:\/\/example\.com\/?lang_id=10 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Add additional file extensions to the list as needed.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg)$
RewriteRule (.*) /images/nophoto.jpg

# Avoid .php Endings
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         https://example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.info$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.at$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.ch$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can usernames contain dots?

Comment: Actually no dots, not even numbers in usernames, but maybe possible in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these directives are directly in the server config (or virtual host), as opposed to a `<Directory>` container or `.htaccess` file.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

*Aside:* The second *condition* here doesn't make sense. It's checking that the initial request maps to a file before appending `.php`. You certainly don't want to append `.php` if the initial request did map to a file. Fortunately, it's entirely redundant since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^([^\.]+)$` excludes dots, so the rule naturally excludes requests that would map to an actual file anyway (unless you have files that don't have file extensions - very unlikely).

Only the first *condition* that checks that the request does not map to a directory is actually being used here.

This then essentially rewrites the request unconditionally, regardless of whether the target `.php` file exists or not. It would be preferable to check for this first and this will help to resolve your conflict with usernames (as you suggest).

NB: You should really be using the `REQUEST_URI` variable here (or `$1` backreference) instead of `REQUEST_FILENAME`. `REQUEST_FILENAME` is intended to contain the absolute filesystem path, so appending this to `DOCUMENT_ROOT` does not ordinarily make sense. It's just that when used in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context, `REQUEST_FILENAME` contains the same as `REQUEST_URI` (ie. the root-relative URL-path).

> Works great, website.com/login.php becomes website.com/login

*Aside:* This rule actually does the exact opposite. `/login` becomes `/login.php`. The other way round would be an external redirect and a different directive.

So, change the above to read:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

This checks that the request + `.php` exists before rewriting the request. There's no need to check that the request does not map to a directly before checking that the request + `.php` does map to a file.

No need to backslash-escape the literal dot in the regex character class.

No need for the `NC` or `QSA` flags. The regex is already case-insensitive because it matches both a-z and A-Z. And any query string from the request is automatically appended, unless you explicitly include a query string in the *substitution*.

Then, if usernames cannot contain dots, you can use the following rule to manage `/username`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You would likely need the condition that first checks that the request does not map to a directory.

If, however, *usernames* can contain does then remove the dot from the regex and include an additional condition to exclude requests that already map to files (in the document root):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Summary

```
# Extensionless URLs
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Rewrite "/Usernames"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite for your great answer. However, by using your "summary", I am getting the "profile not found" custom error message on every page request, so I updated the original question inclusive the full config to have a quick look if there are other rules overwriting your summary perhaps?